# Change image in drawablle inside an editText field

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am building a password visibility toggle system (Without using TextInputLayout).
It is working, but I wan to change the icon when user clicks on the icon inside the EditText input field.

**xml**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_border"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/eye_image"
    android:hint="Your Password" />
```

**eye_image.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/eye_show"
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp"
    />
</layer-list>
```

**java code**

```
password.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (password.getRight() - password.getCompoundDrawables() 
[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here
if(password.getTransformationMethod().equals(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance())){

                        //Show Password
                       ((ImageView)(view)).setImageResource(R.drawable.eye_show);
password.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        password.setSelection(password.getText().length());
                    }
                    else{
                        //Hide Password
 ((ImageView)(view)).setImageResource(R.drawable.eye_show);
password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        password.setSelection(password.getText().length());
                    }
               }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I get this error - **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView**

I just want to make the image in the **eye_image.xml** drawable which is placed at the right of the editText to change to another image onClick

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, This did the trick

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.eye_image2, 0);
```